# Which iPhone OS version shows the maps application?

Tags: iphone

I have a 3.0 iPhone and the maps show blank.

what earliest iPhone version allows me to view maps in the built in maps app.?

Answer (score 0):

Maps were available from the very first iOS version.

I think they might have changed the API, and that might be the reason why your 3.0 Maps app does not work. Also you might be using a messed up DNS server or have some kind of filtering on your router or firewall.

What is the reason you are using 3.0 anyway?

Comment: IT just doesn't display the map.

Comment: Which means it can't receive any data from Googles map servers. And this might be due to outdated APIs or network connectivity problems. Update your iOS?

Comment: 1. In case I wasn't clear - I don't mean the map kit in the SDK, I meant the maps app that comes with the iPhone itself

Comment: 2. Update ok but to which earliest version? 3.1 will do?